# Should an object know what other objects have it?

Tags: java, oop

For instance, I have two classes: Book and Customer. Customer has a List which contains all the Books it purchased. I can easily look up a Customer's purchase history with this design.

However, if I want to know how many Customers have bought a particular Book, usually I would look up all Customers purchase history and get those who bought this particular Book. This can be a time consuming looking up process. I wonder if it would be a better approach to add a List inside the Book class, and add all the Customers who bought this particular book to this List.

I wonder if my approach would be better/worse in terms of design. This is definitely making Book-Customer strongly coupled, but I am not sure if there is other ways to implement such method.

Comment: The list of books and who purchased what belongs to the bookstore, not to the book.

Comment: is it possible to have a counter set up for each book, i.e., 5 copies of Book A,and for each customer that takes out a boot you subtract the count?  This way, you know with 5 books total, and 3 taken out, that there are 2 left.

This also will help with "out of stock issues"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, to be pure, neither the book nor the customer should know about each other. I would instead create a third class, Purchase, containing references to the customer and the book, the date ordered, date shipped, price paid, etc.

Then I'd have a `Map<Customer, List<Purchase>>` and optionally a `Map<Book, List<Purchase>>`.

Comment: Wouldn't it use more memories/storage space? I mean I already have Customer and Book objects, and adding more objects seems to be memory consuming. Can memory/storage space be totally out of concern today?

Comment: @hybpro it would add only a small amount of extra memory usage. The class definition itself uses a negligible amount of memory. It's the objects (instances) that use up most of the memory, and adding a Purchase class will only add a small amount of extra memory requirement per instance, since most fields in the Purchase class will have been otherwise present in either the Customer or Book classes. So you're moving fields rather than adding new ones. The flexibility this adds is usually worth it - unless you are on a severely memory-limited device such as a very old smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

Even Customer class having reference to list of books is not that great.

Keep both Customer and Book classes unaware of each other. Instead maintain maps for your quick reference. e.g. -

```
Map<Customer, List<Book>> customerToBooks;
Map<Book, List<Customer>> bookToCustomers;
```

And manipulate these maps through `assignBook(Customer c, Book b)` and `returnBook(Customer c, Book b)` methods

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is check the list inside of the customer's class checking the book purchase history like so:

Customer.java

```
public class Customer{
    public Set<Book> purchases = new HashSet<Book>();

    public void purchaseBook(Book b){
        purchases.add(b);
    }
}
```

Original class:

```
public Set<Customer> customers = new HashSet<Customer>();

public Set<Customer> getCustomersFromBook(Book b){
    Set<Customer> ret = new HashSet<Customer>();
    for(Customer c : customers){
        if(c.purchases.contains(b)){
            ret.add(c);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Or you can do the same sort of thing, but with the customers inside of a `Set` in the `Book` class.